# How to create a context menu in a RichTextBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, richtextbox, contextmenu

I want to create a context menu in a RichTextBox. I want Cut, Copy, Paste options when I right click on the RichTextBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenu):

```
Private Sub InitializeMyContextMenu()
     ' Create the contextMenu and the MenuItem to add.
     Dim contextMenu1 As New ContextMenu()
     Dim menuItem1 As New MenuItem("C&ut")
     Dim menuItem2 As New MenuItem("&Copy")
     Dim menuItem3 As New MenuItem("&Paste")

     ' Use the MenuItems property to call the Add method
     ' to add the MenuItem to the MainMenu menu item collection. 
     contextMenu1.MenuItems.Add(menuItem1)
     contextMenu1.MenuItems.Add(menuItem2)
     contextMenu1.MenuItems.Add(menuItem3)

     ' Assign mainMenu1 to the rich text box.
     richTextBox1.ContextMenu = contextMenu1
 End Sub
```